# Dirt Rod seems to only remove dirt, not move it around?

Tags: terraria

I got the Dirt Rod and started using it on, well, Dirt Blocks.

I thought I managed to move them around at first, but when I moved to my nearly totally flooded Underground, the Dirt I pick up with it seems to disappear and not be moved elsewhere.

Is that what it does, just remove Dirt Blocks?

Comment: Please show a screenshot, or better yet, a video.

Answer (score 6):

Here, I just made this:

[image]

Just what the GIF says, left click and hold to drag the dirt, then let go of the left click to drop the dirt like sand.

Note: If you want the dirt to break, just let go of the left click while your mouse is inside of a tile.